# Spring Security: Can other beans access the global AuthenticationManagerBuilder?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have set up the boilerplate spring security Configurer:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
private DataSource datasource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   // ...setting up security for routes, etc.
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
      // here I have access to the AuthenticationManagerBuilder
      // I can associate it with my datasource, set the password encoder, etc.
 JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new   JdbcUserDetailsManager();
    userDetailsService.setDataSource(datasource);
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);

}
```

But what I want is to be able to access that AuthenticationManagerBuilder from another bean like this:

```
@Service
public class MyUserService {

@Autowired
AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder; 

public void createUser(...) {
//use builder here...
    JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
    userDetailsService.setDataSource(datasource);
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
      .passwordEncoder(encoder);
    builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);
    userDetailsService.createUser(new User(...));
}
```

Is there any way to access from other beans the same `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` instance that is automatically passed to the `configure()` method?

Comment: Why do you want to perform configuration in MyUserService? This should be done in a configuration class?

Comment: I don't really want to perform configuration but I want to create users that are bound to the security context of the application. It seems to create user, I need the UserDetailService an the only way to obtain the correct instance of the UserDetailService is to get it from the AuthenticationManagerBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AuthenticationManagerBuilder is really only meant for building your authentication objects (i.e. UserDetails, AuthenticationProvider, AuthenticationManager). It is not intended to be used within the application itself.

Instead, I would recommend using the UserDetailsManager API. You can create a UserDetailsManager Bean, provide the UserDetailsManager to the AuthenticationManagerBuilder for creating the AuthenticationProvider & AuthenticationManager, then you can use the UserDetailsManager directly within your code.

Something like this:

```
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, UserDetailsService uds) throws Exception { 
      auth
        .userDetailsService(uds)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager udm(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager udm = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        udm.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return udm;
    }
}

@Service
public class MyUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsManager udm; 

    public void createUser(...) {
        //use builder here...
        udm.createUser(new User(...));
    }
}
```

One thing to note is that we leverage the global instance of AuthenticationManagerBuilder. In order to ensure the configureGlobal method is invoked before building the AuthenticationProvider and AuthenticationManager you need to have EnableGlobalAuthentication, EnableWebMvcSecurity or EnableWebSecurity annotations on the Configuration class (our example already does this).

Comment: Yes the ```UserDetailsManager``` is what I needed. Thanks! In case someone else is looking at this, the password that is passed to ```new User(...)``` call has to be encrypted first with the same encoder (i.e. ```BCryptPasswordEncoder()```)